# How to mass-organize iTunes library?

Tags: itunes, ms-office, music

I'd like to try to organize the songs in my iTunes library (rename artists and albums, etc.), but my library's pretty large and it would be time consuming to manually edit my songs via the Get Info screen.

Is there a way to mass-organize your songs? Ideally by exporting your library's song info to Excel, and then importing it back into iTunes?

I've tried exporting a playlist as a .txt file, editing it in Microsoft Excel, resaving it as a .txt file, and importing it back into iTunes, but my changes had no effect.

Comment: You could remove the files entirely from iTunes, make mass changes to their ID3 tags (presuming they are a format that supports those tags) and then import the songs back into iTunes, which will use the new data in the files. You can also highlight a group of songs and do Get Info, and make mass changes that way. Any blank field will be left alone when you click OK.

Answer (score 1):

The free (and open-source) program MusicBrainz Picard would be a good option to consider. It can identify songs and albums by their acoustic ID's and automatically enter the ID3 tags.

The program will "play nice" with iTunes as well. Just use it to organize and tag your music, then do the following (copied from the MusicBrainz Picard website)

1. Open iTunes, then go to File > Add Folder to Library
2. Point it at the top of your iTunes directory ("My Music\iTunes\iTunes Music\Music" on Windows, by default).
3. iTunes will rescan your music.