# Software to organize library?

Tags: itunes, library

Im looking for a program that let me organize my itunes library (So that the CD's that I export instead of saving it like "Track 1",etc, be saved with all the sing info, such as artist, album, etc).

[How to mass-organize iTunes library?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175856/how-to-mass-organize-itunes-library)

I taked a look into that question but Im looking for something more complete, It does not matter if it cotst.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you are looking for? "more complete" can mean a lot of things, so what kind of functionality are you missing in the product recommended in the linked question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Jaikoz might be a good choice for you. This article also has a pretty detailed list of other options: http://lifehacker.com/the-best-apps-for-automatically-cleaning-up-your-music-1561265062

Comment: Thanks, At the end Im using Tune Up. Is the best option, a little expensive.